# ImageMagick no decode delegate

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convert an image with imagemagick, but I'm getting this error:

> convert: no decode delegate for this image format `//i.imgur.com/nTheJ.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.

I'm doing this:

```
convert http://i.imgur.com/nTheJ.jpg -resize 600×600 filarkiv/billeder/produkter/s236-085145.jpg
```

I have the following delegates:

> DELEGATES     freetype jpeg jng mpeg png x11 xml zlib

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Well, you have the JPEG delegate and it says there is a problem.  Which poses the question, what is the matter with the source file?  Or, the JPEG installation.

Comment: Could you clarify what OS you're using, and which version of ImageMagick?

Comment: Your policy.xml file likely has restricted your use of HTTP. Edit your policy.xml file to give read permissions for HTTP.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

substitude the `×` in `-resize 600×600` with a capital `X` and it should work.

```
-resize 600X600
```

Comment: Didn't work for me: ERROR ArgumentError: Didn't recognise the geometry string 100X100

Comment: that is so bizarre. it was working fine with the lowercase "x" until I started converting blob type files. I did what you said and everything worked again.

Answer (score 81):

I had this error when rendering an image using DragonFly in Rails. This happened after I upgraded to Lion (ImageMagick was installed using Brew).

I reinstalled ImageMagick, jpeg, libtiff and jasper (reinstalling ImageMagick wasn't enough by itself).

```
brew uninstall imagemagick jpeg libtiff jasper
brew install imagemagick
```

Prior to that, running

```
identify -list format
```

and jpeg wasn't in the list. After reinstalling the above packages jpeg appeared in the list.

Comment: In my case was missing libpng - installed it with MacPorts, this triggered a rebuild of ImageMagick. .

Comment: Never could get Imagemagick to find TIF files so I used [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) instead. That worked.

Comment: Same situation. Reinstalling imagemagick was not enough--had to specify jpeg.

Comment: awesome answer, Love the "identify -list format" so i can actually see whats missing.  thanks!

Answer (score 26):

for me:

```
 brew reinstall imagemagick --with-libtiff
```

saved the day when dealing with a similar problem, but for tiff files.

UPDATE: one year later and this remains the only way I can get tiff working properly in convert on MacOS X.

Comment: installing this way was critical for me to get TIFF files working properly.  A regular imagemagick install was not working.

Comment: You can use `brew info imagemagick` to see what other options you can reinstall imagemagick with using brew. Very useful.

Comment: `Warning: imagemagick: this formula has no --with-libtiff option so it will be ignored!`

Answer (score 6):

on Ubuntu 16, I had to install the following first (this was not a dev machine but a server):

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autotools-dev libtool pkg-config
```

then to enable the PNG and JPG delegates :

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12 libpng12-dev libjpeg libjpeg-dev
```

followed by

```
./configure
```

(Which should now show that the delegates are enabled)

and then rebuild (`make clean && make` then `sudo make install`)

Answer (score 5):

I had similiar problem. I was missing delegates for JPEG, PNG :

```
apt install libjpeg-dev
apt install libpng-dev

cd ImageMagick-7.1.0-19/
./configure
```

Now check the output is jpeg=yes; png=yes

```
make
sudo make install
```

Now try `convert` or `mogrify`

```
mogrify -path "output/" -resize 1920X1920 some.jpeg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me many hours of searching!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem recently. After Googling for couple of hours, I found out that reason was a CONFLICT between php extentions Gmagick & Imagick. Commenting gmagick.so in php.ini fixed the problem. Hope this will save someone time :)

Answer (score 3):

redhat4.8, If you install from source,
may be can try:

> yum remove libjpeg
>
> wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz
>
> sudo tar xvf jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz -C /usr/local/src/
>
> cd /usr/local/src/jpeg-9a
>
> ./configure --enable-shared
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

than turn in ImageMagick

> cd ImageMagick-6.9.6-4
>
> ./configure
>
> sudo make install
>
> sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 2):

from Phillip Ingram somewhere on the interwebs:

in gentoo use

```
sudo EXTRA_ECONF="--with-png --with-jpeg" emerge imagemagick
```

This is slightly different than Jonathan Horseman's answer since it wasn't an error but rather a need to specify more during the installation.

But the identify command was very useful.

Hope this helps someone (and perhaps me in the future ;).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid syntax (unbalanced quotes, at the least), so it's not clear what was intended here, but it would be helpful.

Comment: @TTT Just remove the quote at the end

Comment: Hopefully that was a cut and paste error with an extra quote, rather than a cut and paste error with something missing ;).  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the solution was a matter of ending the command with `*.{jpg,png}` rather than `*`.

I believe the `*` was picking up / trying to convert hidden files.

Comment: YOU are _the_ man - my mogrify script was failing because it had "no decode delegate for this image format `DB`.  After a bit I realised it was trying to convert directories because I had left * at the end of the command rather than specifying the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for this error to show up is when the file you're trying to convert has no extension.

This may happen, for example, in a Node.js application using `multer` with the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem with TIFF files on ImageMagick v7.0.4-5 on Windows 7.

If this question concerns a Windows OS, then the cause is that Windows can't find the Jpeg (in my case, TIFF) file library (DLL).

### Cause

I had installed ImageMagick without adding it to the Windows `$PATH`.

### Error message

This resulted in error

```
identify: unable to load module 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.4-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_TIFF_.dll':
The specified module could not be found.
 @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1279.
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `TIFF'
 @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
```

### Solution

- Re-install ImageMagick and do add it to the `$PATH`, so that it can find `libtiff`.  Restart your command shell as well.
- First `cd` into ImageMagick's install folder before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

i had the problem and i forgot put to obj downloaded photo against i put path.

file_get_contents($pathToPhoto)

maybe someone help :[

Answer (score 0):

now there is something about the message in ImageMagick docs: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/main/www/advanced-linux-installation.html#L591