# imagemagick -- convert: no decode delegate for this image format `TIFF'

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, tiff, imagemagick-convert, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert an image "img.tif" to "img.jpg" with the following command:

```
convert img.tif img.jpg
```

And this error arises:

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `TIFF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

I've trawled the web for answers, but nothing is working. 
The suggestions from previous people with this problem have been:

```
brew reinstall imagemagick --with-libtiff
```

, which I have done, to no avail.  The call:

```
convert -list configure
```

still gives the following for DELEGATES:

```
DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg png x xml zlib
```

**ANY other suggestions** would be appreciated. 
**Even another way to convert from .tif to .jpg from the command line**.

Comment: See this answer [here][1]. Try uninstalling first then install.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10319327/3506427

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactely the right solution of your problem but it can "do the job".

You could convert from tif to jpg by adding a PNG (which is lossless) converting step:
tif→PNG→jpg

```
 inkscape --export-png=img.png img.tif
```

then

```
convert img.png img.jpg
```

For me, the command

```
convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES
```

returns:

```
DELEGATES     bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jpeg jng jp2 lcms2 lqr lzma openexr pango png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib
```

And I didn't do something special during install so I don't understand why you don't have the "tif" nor the "jpeg" part…

Maybe you can try to install "libtiff-tools" "libjpeg" and "libjpeg-turbo".

The delegates could be found here:
[Imagemagic Delegates](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/)